# Is it possible to create a bootable Ubuntu on a flash drive without Rufus?

Tags: ubuntu, bootable

Can I create a bootable Ubuntu on a flash drive without using Rufus?
Is it possible to create a bootable Ubuntu on a flash drive without Rufus?
I have tried to create a bootable Ubuntu on a flash drive using Rufus and encountered a slight error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following free tools to make a linux bootable USB from Windows:

- [Etcher - balena](https://etcher.balena.io)
- [Universal USB
  Installer aka
  UUI](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)
- [LinuxLive USB Creator](https://www.linuxliveusb.com/)
- [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/)
- [Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/download.html)

I am sure there are MANY more. These are the only ones I have used.